# Ошибка "Could not find field for property during fallback access" в Spring

Tags: java, spring, mvc, hibernate, jpa

Использую Spring MVC + Security Data + Maven + Tomcat + Hibernate.

В общем, имею скрипт, который я сгенерировал с помощью Hibernate в код Java.
Когда хочу создать новый чат, выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

Страница JSP

```
<form:form modelAttribute="chat" method="post">
            <div class="card white">
                <div class="card-content indigo white-text">
                    <p class="center-align" style="font-size:24px;">
                        Создать чат
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content black-text">
                    <spring:hasBindErrors name="chat">
                        <div class="card pink lighten-4 form_login error-mess">
                            <div class="card-content red-text text-darken-4">
                                <p>
                                    <form:errors path="*"/>
                                    <br>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </spring:hasBindErrors>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <form:input id="name" name="name" type="text" path="name" cssClass="validate"/>
                        <label for="name">Имя чата</label>
                    </div>
                        <form:input id="creator" name="creator" type="text" path="creator" cssClass="hide" value="${username}"/>
                    <p>
                        Тип чата:
                        <br>
                        <form:radiobutton cssClass="with-gap" path="type" value="publ" id="type1"/>
                        <label for="type1">Открытый</label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <form:radiobutton cssClass="with-gap" path="type" value="priv" id="type2"  />
                        <label for="type2">Приватный</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo left" type="submit" name="action">Создать</button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form:form>
```

Таблица базы `chat`:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ChatPK.class)
public class Chat {
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]+",message = "Pattern.chat.name")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Size.chat.name")
    private String name;

    //publ = PUBLIC , priv = PRIVATE
    @NotEmpty
    private String type = "publ";
    private String creator;

    public Chat(){}

    public Chat(String name, String type, String creator) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 48)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 4)
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "creator", nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Chat chat = (Chat) o;
        return type == chat.type &&
                Objects.equals(name, chat.name) &&
                Objects.equals(creator, chat.creator);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, type, creator);
    }
}
```

Файл `ChatPK.java`:

```
public class ChatPK implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String creator;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 48)
    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "creator", nullable = false, length = 32)
    @Id
    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ChatPK chatPK = (ChatPK) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, chatPK.name) &&
                Objects.equals(creator, chatPK.creator);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, creator);
    }
}
```

Файл контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new-chat",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newChatPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("chat", new Chat());
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = user.getUsername();
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    return "new-chat";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new-chat", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newChatPagePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("chat") Chat chat, BindingResult result, Model model){
    if(chatService.exists(chat.getName())){
        result.rejectValue("name", "DuplicateKey.chat.name");
        return "new-chat";
    }
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "new-chat";
    }
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = user.getUsername();
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    chat.setCreator(username);
    chatService.addChat(chat);
    return "new-chat";
}
```

В чём может быть ошибка? Если ещё что-то нужно — добавлю.

Comment: Вопрос по прежнему актуален